# Rails - Using a before_filter to run a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, before-filter

I would like this before filter to run every time the page is loaded (for now) to check if an item is over 7 days old or not and if so, run some actions on it to update its attributes.

I have `before_filter :update_it` in the application controller. `update_it` is defined below that in the same controller as:

```
def update_it
  @books = Book.all
  @books.each do |book|
    book.update_queue
  end
end
```

Then `update_queue` is defined in the book model. Here's everything in the model that pertains to this:

```
scope :my_books, lambda {|user_id|
    {:conditions => {:user_id => user_id}}  
  }

  scope :reading_books, lambda {
    {:conditions => {:reading => 1}}
  }

  scope :latest_first, lambda {
    {:order => "created_at DESC"}
  }


  def move_from_queue_to_reading
    self.update_attributes(:queued => false, :reading => 1);
  end

  def move_from_reading_to_list
    self.update_attributes(:reading => 0);
  end

  def update_queue
    days_gone = (Date.today - Date.parse(Book.where(:reading => 1).last.created_at.to_s)).to_i

    # If been 7 days since last 'currently reading' book created
    if days_gone >= 7

        # If there's a queued book, move it to 'currently reading'
        if Book.my_books(user_id).where(:queued => true)
            new_book = Book.my_books(user_id).latest_first.where(:queued => true).last
            new_book.move_from_queue_to_reading
            currently_reading = Book.my_books(user_id).reading_books.last
            currently_reading.move_from_reading_to_list

        # Otherwise, create a new one
        else
            Book.my_books(user_id).create(:title => "Sample book", :reading => 1)

        end
    end
  end
```

My relationship is that a book belongs_to a user and a user has_many books. I'm showing these books in the view through the user show view, not that it matters though.

So the errors I keep getting are that `move_from_queue_to_reading` and `move_from_reading_to_list` are undefined methods. How can this be? I'm clearly defining them and then calling them below. I really am at a loss and would greatly appreciate some insight into what I'm doing wrong. I'm a beginner here, so any structured criticism would be great :)

**EDIT**

The exact error message I get and stack trace is as follows:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#show
undefined method `move_from_queue_to_reading' for nil:NilClass

app/models/book.rb:41:in `update_queue'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:22:in `block in update_it'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:21:in `each'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:21:in `update_it'
```

Comment: Can you check that `new_book` and `currently_reading` variables are not `nil`?

Comment: Are the two methods that can't be found in a `protected` or `private` section?

Comment: @PinnyM ```new_book``` is not nill if I run ```new_book = Book.where(:queued => true).last``` in the console. It returns a book. Same thing with ```currently_reading```.

Comment: @DonCruickshank No they are not.

Comment: Perhaps, but that's not the same as `Book.my_books(user_id).where(:queued => true).last`.  In any event, it may help if you post a stack trace.

Comment: Just posted it above in the question. I'm not sure how to do that in the console, since ```my_books``` is a scope.

Comment: As per your stack trace - the offending method _is_ being called on a nil object: `undefined method `move_from_queue_to_reading' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Ah okay. So ```.my_books(user_id)``` is invalid somehow. That's found above in ```scope :my_books```. Amy I calling that scope method wrong?

Comment: Wait you know what. I'm not defining ```user_id``` anywhere in this model. Could that be the problem?

Comment: No, it's not wrong. `user_id` is an attribute of the current `book` object - please see my answer update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the collection returned is an empty array (which is still 'truthy' when tested).  So calling `.last` is returning `nil` to the `new_book` and `currently_reading` local variables. Try changing:

```
if Book.my_books(user_id).where(:queued => true)
```

to:

```
if Book.my_books(user_id).where(:queued => true).exists?
```

Additionally, you are modifying the scope when finding `currently_reading`.  This can potentially cause the query to again return no results.  Change:

```
currently_reading.move_from_reading_to_list
```

to:

```
currently_reading.move_from_reading_to_list if currently_reading
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still getting the undefined methods though.

Comment: I think you just solved the problem I've been pulling my hair out over for 3 days. I'm gonna test it a bit more, but I swear if you just solved my problem I'm going to come to wherever you are and hug you.

Comment: Please. Don't. Glad to help.

Comment: :) Okay so I've definitely made progress, because every time the page loads it's going through all 300 of the books in the db and checking to update them and it takes like 45 seconds so I'll have to change that (I think it's updating ALL the books in the db, not just the certain ones we want it to). So once it goes through that, it's not adding a book if there isn't one queued up. Does ```Book.my_books(user_id).create(:title => "Sample book", :reading => 1)``` look right to you?

Comment: Nope.  Try, `user.books.create(:title => "Sample book", :reading => 1)`.  This assumes your book `belongs_to` a user that `has_many` books.

Comment: Okay it's updating all the records with that change made now. I think I'm like somehow doubling the amount of books every time I refresh the page cause it's literally taken 2 minutes to load all these books. I can't even tell what it's doing it's going so fast. My computer is sounding like it's gonna blow up

Comment: Perhaps this logic isn't quite what you wanted.  Can you revise your question and clarify what exactly it is you want to do with this `before_filter`?  Better yet, make it a separate question since this isn't related to the problem you started with.

Comment: Well I have posted about this before and the logic might be explained better there. The logic was a little different then as I was going to run a cron job instead of a before filter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116242/rails-update-attributes-using-rake-task-need-help-troubleshooting-model-metho